# comparing pairs of vertices in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, graph

I want to traverse through all the vertices from a given set of vertices and compare the distance between two pairs. Suppose my vertices list is as follows:

```
(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10),(11,12)
```

I want to traverse the set of vertices in the following way:

1st iteration:

```
for pair (1,2) and (3,4) I want to compare it with [(5,6),(7,8)],[(7,8),  (9,10)]and[(9,10),(11,12)]
```

2nd iteration:

```
for pair (3,4) and (5,6) I want to compare it with [(7,8),(9,10)]and[(9,10),(11,12)]
```

3rd iteration:

```
for pair (7,8) and (9,10) I want to compare it with [(9,10),(11,12)]
```

how will I do this using nested loop in java? I want to store the set of vertices in an arraylist. I have tried in the following way but getting exception:

```
 for(i=0;i<arraylist.size();i++)
 {
     for(j=i+2;j<arraylist.size();j++
      {
           //x,y,u,v are objects of the vertex class
             x=arraylist.get(i);
             y=arraylist.get(i+1);
             u=arraylist.get(j);
             v=arraylist.get(j+1);

       }
  }
```

What additional change will I need to make in the above code fragment to traverse the vertex set as I explained above?

Comment: And the exception you're getting would be? Or is it an error, since your second for loop is missing a trailing parenthesis?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 20, Size: 20
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
@ Jonny Henly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception, because you try go `get()` items with index that are not in the list (see [Arraylist.get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-) )

```
 j<arraylist.size()

 v=arraylist.get(j+1);  <- (j+1) can become arraylist.size().
```

So you should limit your loops to:

```
  j<arraylist.size()-1
```

Comment: what will be the solution then? how will I use the nested loop without getting exception? @RobAu

Comment: See the last line of my answer. Set the limits for `i` and `j` to `arraylist.size()-1` in the for loops.